# Legal Issues Regarding Deletion of Records in SQL Server 2008

Tags: security, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I securely destroy some data using sql server 2008 ? (using DoD secure wipe or an equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553590/how-can-i-securely-destroy-some-data-using-sql-server-2008-using-dod-secure-wi)

We have a requirement for a feature that has legal implications. When we delete records from SQL Server (2008 in our case), the deleted records need to be irrecoverable from SQL Server as well as from disk. I'm not that concerned from the SQL Server side, but I'm more concerned at the disk level.

I know there are tools to do secure erasing on disk, but how can you tie that in with deleting records in a database?

My guess is that periodically or at night, a task would have to run the secure erase tool.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Secure deleting is very hard to do correctly. For example on SSDs wear leveling can interfere with overwriting.

Comment: What implications does this requirement have for your backups?

Comment: @Joe - The requirement says to not worry about backups.

Comment: If you don't worry about backups as well, then the other requirement doesn't make sense as the data is always recoverable.

Comment: You mean the system will not be allowed to have backups?  Or that it's OK for the backups to contain the data that must be securely deleted from the live system

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting the SQL data on an encrypted disk would help? After shutting down the server machine no one would be able to recover anything from the disk given the encryption is securely implemented.

If you have enough CPU power you do software encryption. Otherwise there are classical HDDs and SSDs which offer encryption in hardware.

Your description doesn't include enough details to know whether this is an option for you. Just a suggestion for the case you could apply encryption.